# Can't connect to a MySQL Database Server

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I already deploy a MySQL Database server and want to connect it to my WordPress app. I already change the MySQL configuration in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and comment the `bind-address` or change the `bind-address` value from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`. I also have tried to change the `bind-address` value to the IP of the remote server's application that uses the database.

I also already grant a user permission with:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `database`.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

And

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `database`.* TO 'user'@'remotehost';
```

Here is the WordPress DB configuration in `wp-config.php`:

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'databasename' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'username' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'remotehost' );

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
```

What do I miss?

Comment: it is a bad idea to allow connction from all sources, this could be a security hazard

Comment: @nbk so what can I do to allow only a specific IP address to access the DB? I also already tried to change the `bind-address` value to the IP of the remote server's application that uses the database.

Comment: given access from the4 internet directly tthe database is as i already saud a security hazard, also you have to deplay your access data in the app so a further security risk. Rest api handles the communication with the database and the app, as wordpress is a php script that is a server side language, i have difficulties to understand what you trying to do .